# Export xgboost tree plot to image in R

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to understand the tree of an xgb model through a tree plot - `xgb.plot.tree().`

Unfortunately the plot is too crowded and R session turns too slow. So to better zoom in and analyse the tree I would like to export it to an image with high resolution.

With the following code I just get a blank .png image.

```
> png("c:\\path\\tree.png", width = 8000, height = 6000)
> xgb.plot.tree(features, xgb_model, n_first_tree = 2)
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

How can I export the plot to a png?

Answer (score 4):

```
gr <- xgb.plot.tree(model=xbg_model, trees=0:1, render=FALSE)
library(DiagrammeR)
export_graph(gr, 'tree.pdf', width=3000, height=4000)
```

`export_graph` depends on some other packages. It would notify you through error messages about whether any of those packages are missing and need to be installed.

Note that a few new parameters were introduced in the [recent update to xgb.plot.tree](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/1939):

- `trees` allows to select any specific tree or a set of trees to plot. This alone may help you with slowness and crowdedness.
- `render` when set to FALSE, it allows to obtain a DiagrammeR object of class `dgr_graph`, which could be further rendered or exported in variety of formats.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to save this plot to a file. 
Note that for `export_graph` to work, the `DiagrammeRsvg` and `rsvg` packages must also be installed.

    `library(DiagrammeR)
    gr <- xgb.plot.tree(model=bst, trees=0:1, render=FALSE)
    export_graph(gr, 'tree.pdf', width=1500, height=1900)
    export_graph(gr, 'tree.png', width=1500, height=1900)`